# Не одобряют приложение в App Store

Tags: appstore, xcode, ios, objective-c, apple

На iOS девайсе и всех симуляторах приложение работает отлично, но при добавлении его в App Store, его отклонили ответив:

> 2.1: Apps that crash will be rejected
>
> We found your app crashed on launch so
> we were unable to review it.
>
> We have attached detailed crash logs
> for your reference.
>
> Please revise your app and test it on
> a device to ensure it will launch
> without crashing, and that it runs as
> expected, before resubmitting.
>
> For discrete code-level questions, you
> may wish to consult with Apple
> Developer Technical Support. If you
> have crash logs, symbolicate the crash
> logs before contacting Apple Developer
> Technical Support.
>
> If you have difficulty reproducing
> this issue, please try testing the
> workflow as described in Testing
> Workflow with Xcode's Archive feature.

Comment: подозреваю, что на 5s не тестили. 64битная ios - это не тоже что эмулятор. у меня была проблема с приведением типов (в одной библиотеке).

Comment: симмулятор там, а не эмулятор - в этом основная проблема, симмулятор iOS - это фактически откомпиленные библиотеки iOs под x86-64 + немного обвязки-имитации оборудования, в отличии от эмулятолра андройда который преобразует команды из родного для большинства девайсов ARM в x86

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Маловато информации, ниже приведу свои вопросы/предположения, может решение и найдется среди них:

1. Насколько помню, ребята из эппл присылают крашлог в таком случае, что в нем? Обычно по нему понятно что именно упало
2. Вы проверяли его только на симмуляторах? Плохая идея - симмулятор это не то же что устройство, там разные бинарники используются и сильно круче аппаратные средства. Из того что я видел - могут быть некоторые кодеки которых нет в айоси, из-за настроек десктопной системы в названиях файлов не учитывался регистр, ну и размер внешней памяти весь хард и оперативки несколько гигов
3. Проверяли ли вы его на всех версиях поддерживаемых осей? В разных версиях сдк доступны разные методы, икскод об этом не говорит, но приложение упадет в рантайме
4. Еще один возможный вариант - вы все проверяли на дебаг версии, а где-то стоит что-то типа #ifdef DEBUG #else и в релизе другой код
5. Запуск программы из икскода обычно приводит к дополнительным затратам времени на связь с икскодом и передачу ему вяческих данных (логов и тп), сам видел вариант когда что-то падало при таком запуске по таймауту, но тот же самый бинарь  нормально отрабатывал без икскода (в смысле залил прилагу на девайс, запустил из икскода - оно упало, запустил еще раз просто нажав на нее на девайсе - все ок, проверено было несколько раз независимо на нескольких девайсах). У вас возможна обратная ситуация - что-то успевает корректно завершиться или не успевает задеаочиться из-за задержки
6. Икскод любит оставлять ресурсы от прошлого запуска на девайсе-симмуляторе, при этом бывает что файл по ошибке удален или же поврежден код его копирования, например, в документы, но т.к. этот ресурс был скопирован на девайс/в определенное место в бандле на одном из предыдущих запусков когда все это работало, у разраба все хорошо, но при запуске с нуля будут проблемы. Встречал даже такую проблему с объектниками, причем сразу у двух разрабов все было хорошо, а у меня не собралось т.к. я после выгрузки из гита очистил проект и старый объектник у меня удалился. Частный вариант - старый баг с локализацией, икскод старых версий почему-то при создании новой локализации файла (*.strings или ксиба) упорно прописывал в проекте абсолютный путь до этого файла на конкретной машине, после чего оно естественно не собиралось ни у кого кроме разработчика

Comment: 1. Да, есть такое, 4 файла с примерно одинаковым названием про iPad: Tap Tap_2014-05-13-175459_ATL-iPad.crash
приложение сделано только для iPhone.
2. На iPhone 5 ещё.
3. Приложение только для iOS 7 и выше.
4. Это уж врятли.
5. Запускается норм и через XCode и без него.
6. Удалял полностью с девайса и запускал ещё раз - всё ок.

Comment: Вот http://the-balls.tk/Crash.zip

Comment: 9   Foundation                     0x000000018701717c -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 120
10  Foundation                     0x00000001870170e8 +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 52
11  Tap Tap                        0x00000001000d62b0 0x1000cc000 + 41648
12  UIKit                          0x0000000189560558 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 312

У вас что-то не то передается в [NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:], скорее всего nil вместо строки, откуда именно дергается непонятно, но скорее всего из application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: Ну с файлами у меня связано только 2 участка кода:
https://pp.vk.me/c616521/v616521663/e8c6/GiCvavnPiEg.jpg
https://pp.vk.me/c616521/v616521663/e8ce/0yj_AMuSNFM.jpg

Comment: в принципе, при [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:nil encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; действительно происходит падение с похожим стеком функций, но почему он там у вас nil получается с ходу не знаю

Comment: You.sc что за файл? Может его нет в ресурсах?

Comment: Честно говоря, там в любом случае краша не должно быть - по идее есть две парадигмы работы с ошибками - либо ты кидаешь исключение, либо возвращаешь код или спецобъект ошибки, а этот метод имеет NSError ** в параметрах, но при этом все в резутате падает по экспепшену. Если только где-то внутри приложения еще что-то сильно накручено типа NSURLProtocol

Comment: А ё маё! В общем совершенно забыл про песню которая загружалась в AppDelegate.m, но не играла. После я её удалил, а код оставил.

Comment: Таки чувство не подвело, в ресурсах дело ), не поленитесь используйте AppCode все файлики такого рода будут подсвечиваться как ворнинги.