# Поддержка последней версии iOS

Tags: xcode, ios

Команда review сказала что приложение скрешилось на ipad 7.1.1 , но я не делал поддержку для 7 iOS,
я делал для 5-6 версии! Обязательно поддерживать новую версию и iPad?

Comment: По данным независимых рейтингов семерка стоит на 90% устройств, остальные это образно говоря бабушки-дедушки которые не знают как нажать кнопку "обновить". В приложении для аппстора поддерживать последнюю версию нужно в первую очередь, потом уже все остальное.

Comment: Помоему, обязательно. Просто иначе это нарушает планы масонов, делать по работающее только на новых устройствах, дабы повысить их продаваемость ^_^

Comment: По поводу iPad вопросы могут быть если вы указали проект как Universal, а не как для одной платформы, а он одну из них не поддерживает

Comment: Запустите хотя бы на симуляторе iOS 7 и протестируйте)

Answer (score 1):

поддержка последней версии обязательна вроде бы (да и крайне не логично ее не поддерживать), а конкретно с выходом семерки стало обязательно еще и ее дизайн поддерживать.

Что касается краша, ревью присылают крашлоги, в них обычно есть причина. Что конкретно без них ни угадать, возможные причины когда-то описывал тут: [Не одобряют приложение в App Store](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/320095/objective-c-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-app-store)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете ограничить только минимальную deployment target, но никак не максимальную, так что да, вам придется поддерживать последнюю релизную версию iOS в любом случае